# User independent deployment from private Github repository

Tags: git, github

I want to use the webhooks to trigger a deploy of a private repository.

But I don't want it to happen with SSH-keys or OAuth tokens which are from my Github account. The server that handles the deployment is used by many other people.

It would be nice if I could generate a token or key that can be used to clone from a specific repo only. But has nothing todo with my Github account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for GitHub's [deploy keys](https://developer.github.com/guides/managing-deploy-keys/#deploy-keys):

> ### Deploy keys
>
> A deploy key is an SSH key that is stored on your server and grants access to a single GitHub repository. This key is attached directly to the repository instead of to a personal user account.

Note in particular these two cons mentioned by GitHub:

> 2. The key has full read/write access to the repository.
> 3. Deploy keys are usually not protected by a passphrase, making the key easily accessible if the server is compromised.

In your repository's settings there is a tab on the left for Deploy Keys. Simply add a key here and it can be used for access to that single repository.